ReferenceError: descriptor is not defined while debugging in intellij
When I debug in intellij idea ultimate (version 2024.1.1) with vitest I always see the following error at the top: 
With the following information:
ReferenceError: descriptor is not defined
    at eval (eval at <anonymous> (C:\Users\<user>\Documents\Projecten\<project>\test\common\utils\localization\locale-helper.test.ts:34:9), <anonymous>:1:1)
    at C:\Users\<user>\Documents\Projecten\<project>\test\common\utils\localization\locale-helper.test.ts:34:9
    at file:///C:/Users/<user>/Documents/Projecten/<project>/node_modules/@vitest/runner/dist/index.js:135:14
    at file:///C:/Users/<user>/Documents/Projecten/<project>/node_modules/@vitest/runner/dist/index.js:60:26
    at runTest (file:///C:/Users/<user>/Documents/Projecten/<project>/node_modules/@vitest/runner/dist/index.js:781:17)
    at runSuite (file:///C:/Users/<user>/Documents/Projecten/<project>/node_modules/@vitest/runner/dist/index.js:909:15)
    at runSuite (file:///C:/Users/<user>/Documents/Projecten/<project>/node_modules/@vitest/runner/dist/index.js:909:15)
    at runFiles (file:///C:/Users/<user>/Documents/Projecten/<project>/node_modules/@vitest/runner/dist/index.js:958:5)
    at startTests (file:///C:/Users/<user>/Documents/Projecten/<project>/node_modules/@vitest/runner/dist/index.js:967:3)
    at file:///C:/Users/<user>/Documents/Projecten/<project>/node_modules/vitest/dist/chunks/runtime-runBaseTests.oAvMKtQC.js:116:7

With this tsconfig:
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES2022",
    "module": "ES2022",
    "lib": [
      "es2022"
    ],
    "moduleResolution": "Bundler",
    "noEmit": true,
    "declaration": true,
    "strict": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "noImplicitThis": true,
    "alwaysStrict": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": false,
    "noUnusedParameters": false,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": false,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "inlineSourceMap": true,
    "inlineSources": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "strictPropertyInitialization": false,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "typeRoots": [
      "./node_modules/@types"
    ]
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "cdk.out"
  ],
  "include": [
    ".eslintrc.js",
    "**/*.ts"
  ]
}

What am I missing/ doing wrong for this error to happen while debugging (or atleast assume that this shouldnt happen).
Edit add testcase:
describe('Localization helper', () => {

    ...

    test('messages correctly gives the english language', () => {
        let response = LocaleHelper.messages('en').WIDGET_TITLE_DEFAULT_CLASS;

        expect(response).toBe('Class change');
    });

    ...
});


What does the descriptor definition look like? Please share a code snippet that reproduces the issue.

@lena the test case and the class which is tested does not have a variable or something named descriptor. (nothing in my project has this name)

unfortunately I failed to reproduce the issue. Would it be possible to narrow the problem down to a minimal repo project and share this with us in a new youtrack ticket (https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/WEB)?
